# Is it possible to run IPhone apps on a virtual machine

Tags: ios-simulator

is it possible to run an IPhone app on a windows VM. I'd like to build a test suite for  IPhoneapplications. Will I have to buy extra machines. I already have IMac's and Iphone 3G, but these are being used for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are sites out there that let you download VMWare images of the MacOS. Running the iPhone simulator on windows [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866211/success-with-os-x-and-vmware-for-iphone-development) been done [before](http://blog.jdevelop.eu/2009/05/17/create-iphone-apps-with-a-mac-os-x-vmware-machine/). Can't say how legal it is though.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone simulator is only for Mac OS X. You cannot run it on any other platform.

Answer (score 0):

> I already have IMac's

I'm assuming you mean an iMac and it got capitalized.

Why couldn't you use this iMac to run the iPhone simulator on?  Are you not the one who is using this mac for development?

Having the dev tools on a machine wont stop you from running the simulator on it.

Answer (score 0):

OSX cannot be legally run in a VM. The server version is virtualizable, but much more expensive. There is currently no other solution for non-OSX iPhone development.