# How can I test a web application online in an iOS emulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, emulation

I just want to test [a reveal.js presentation](http://blueseed.com/presentations/startups.html) on an iPhone, because I suspect it crashes Safari. Unfortunately I don't have convenient access to a physical iPhone or iPad.

From what I've seen here on SO, [there aren't any real iOS emulators to begin with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522463/is-it-possible-to-run-iphone-apps-on-a-virtual-machine/1522504#1522504), let alone one hooked to a web frontend, but I'm hoping for a more recent development in the area, akin to [Manymo for Android](http://gigaom.com/mobile/meet-manymo-a-web-based-android-emulator/).

Comment: I made some tests.. sometimes it crashes.. sometime it working well but with lags. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Are there emulators that get you close? Probably. But the iOS simulator run on a Mac is your best option. Well, second best. The best is actually running on an iPhone. If you're talking about something as serious as crashing the browser, there's a good chance a Web-based simulator probably won't produce the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Apple released a remote web inspector with iOS 6, that you can use from the iOS simulator in the same way you'd use firebug or others.

Check this tutorial for more info: 
[how-to web inspector](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/)